# how to edit specific item in qtableview?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview

Is there a way to edit specific item in qtableview given the row and col value? For example, I want to increment its value every second. Here is my tablemodel. Thanks

```
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, datain, headerdata, parent=None, *args): 
        """ datain: a list of lists
            headerdata: a list of strings
        """
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args) 
        self.arraydata = datain
        self.headerdata = headerdata


    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata) 

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        try:
            return len(self.arraydata[0]) 
        except:
            return 0
    def data(self, index, role): 
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant() 
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant() 
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()]) 

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):

        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QVariant(self.headerdata[col])
        return QVariant()

    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number.
        """
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
        self.arraydata = sorted(self.arraydata, key=operator.itemgetter(Ncol))        
        if order == Qt.DescendingOrder:
            self.arraydata.reverse()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could increment the value directly in your model, and emit a `dataChanged` signal from the model.

For example, add a method like this to the model class:

```
def incrementData(row, column):
    self.arraydata[row][column] += 1
    idx = self.index(row, column)
    self.emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), idx, idx)
```